# Unable to use dynamic variable as column name in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Am trying to use dynamic column name in php mysql update but am getting error
Here is code

```
 $time=date("H");
 $video_view = 234
 $update_query = "UPDATE videos SET ".  $time . "= {$video_view} WHERE id={$id}";
```

Here is the error

```
 UPDATE videos SET 14= 200079 WHERE id=1Query failedYou have an error in  
  your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB  
 server version for the right syntax to use near '14= 200079 WHERE id=1' at line 1
```

Comment: Your column actually contains all integers? what is the value of `$time`?

Comment: Column names should start with characters

Comment: @Jens They should but is "legal". They just need to treat them correctly.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I never say that is not "legal". But "legal" must not be good. That's why this is a comment

Comment: Your column (hopefully) isn't actually the number `14`... is it? Post the table structure and we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should really use [prepared statements and bound parameters](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp).
If your column really got the name '14' like in the variable `$time` then you can try this

```
 $update_query = "UPDATE videos SET `".  $time . "` = {$video_view} WHERE id={$id}";
```

So far as I know column names should stand between `` because of reserved names like numbers or function names.
I would avoid it because it will make those errors und I don't know if the query does make sense

Comment: please explain this. The question should get a proper answer

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Turn the tide against teaching/propagating sloppy and dangerous coding practices. If you post an answer without prepared statements [you may want to consider this before posting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344703/). Additionally [a more valuable answer comes from showing the OP the right method](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290789/1011527).